# reverse order of items in a Java byte[] array

Tags: java, arrays, utf-8, reverse

i have a problem reversing the order of items in a bytearray correctly. I want to flip the following String to the one below:

> original "\u042F\u0490\u0418\u0432\u0435\u0442"
>
> flipped  "\u0442\u0435\u0432\u0418\u0490\u042F"

I tried someonething like this, but this doesn't work.

```
public byte[] invert(byte[] input) {
    ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.wrap(input);
    bb.order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN);
    byte[] b = bb.array();
    return b;
}
```

any ideas?

Comment: Your example suggests that you want to *reverse chars* (which has nothing to do with endianness) rather than invert bytes. Note that chars are 16 bits, while bytes are 8 bits. What is your actual end goal here?

Comment: I see, so i have to revert every 2 bytes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will do what your example shows you're looking for:

```
String reversed = new StringBuilder(str).reverse().toString();
```

You may need to decode a `byte[]` to a `String`, and then encode the reversed `String` back to a `byte[]` using the correct character encoding.

Comment: Note that this answer transparently handles surrogates.  Nice.  I did not know about the `reverse()` method!

Answer (score 0):

Don't try to treat Unicode characters as bytes!  The simplest way to do this is create a String (`String(byte[])`) get the characters (`String.toCharArray()`) and write them into a `char[]` in reverse order, then go back to a byte array via a String again.